# Best Method To Create A Very Minimally Interactive Slideshow of Images On iPad

Tags: iphone, flash, ipad, appcelerator

A client of mine wants to show her "listing presentations" (she's a Realtor) to clients on her iPad. A Listing Presentation is normally a slideshow that shows how a Realtor can help the client.

She simply wants a slideshow that she can gesture from slide to slide, and perhaps a small button that allows her to email the slide or some information to the client on the spot.

What would be the best method to accomplish this? Flash Hack, Adobe AIR, Simple Appcelerator App, Native iPad App?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a native iPad app and modify the Three20 library for iPad, it has classes for slideshow viewer, retrieval of images from lists of URL's etc.

All you would need to do is change the xib files / code layout for the viewer class to take into account the larger iPad screen.